# Using constructor injection in @Application bean causes a circular reference

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, runtime-error

I have a medium-sized spring application. When I refactored some loc I noticed the following behaviour:

As it is, the injection is working fine:

```
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
…
```

When I try to use constructor injection, <s>the environment is null</s> my application tells me it can't create my config bean due to a circular reference:

```
public class AppConfig {

    private final Environment env;
    private final IndexableService indexableService;

    @Autowired
    public AppConfig(Environment env, IndexableService indexableService) {
        this.env = env;
        this.indexableService = indexableService;
    }
…
```

*somewhere down the stack:*

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

I tried out some solutions that I found online, none of which helped. How can I even properly debug this? How can I find where the circular reference is created?

---

EDIT:

[stacktrace on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/WKp2U8jH)

[log on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/0bzAimud)

---

EDIT 2:

IndexableService class:

```
package de.xx.yy.server.service;

import de.xx.yy.server.model.Indexable;

import java.util.List;

public interface IndexableService {

    List<Indexable> search(String searchString);

}
```

Implementation of the class:

```
package de.xxx.yyy.server.service;

import de.xxx.yyy.server.model.Indexable;
import io.leangen.graphql.annotations.GraphQLArgument;
import io.leangen.graphql.annotations.GraphQLQuery;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class IndexableServiceImpl implements IndexableService {

    private final Searcher searcher;

    @Autowired
    public IndexableServiceImpl(Searcher searcher) {
        this.searcher = searcher;
    }

    @GraphQLQuery(name = "search")
    public List<Indexable> search(@GraphQLArgument(name = "searchString") String searchString) {
        return searcher.search(searchString);
    }

}
```

PS: Before, my environment has just been null (that's why the line is striked). I was unable to reproduce the null-environment, now I get the circular reference error.

Comment: I would put a breakpoint on `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException` and track what *exactly* caused it. The exception itself is pretty clear.

Comment: Please provide complete exception log?

Comment: @ThomasPötzsch IndexableService class is custom class? Provide it too.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman there you go

Comment: Isn't `indexIdRepository` failing to be created sooner than `IndexableService`?

Comment: @Thomas  if you are using spring 4.3 or greater there is no need to use @-Autowired over the constructor since its uses  Implicit Constructor Injection try that and let us know

Comment: @ManojKrishna I just tried it - it didn't work. I will change the rest of my code to Implicit Constructor Injection, though! thx for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is due to dependency missing

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticSearch' defined in file [/Users/ry77/Workspace/Campus/$PROJECT-server/target/$COMPANY.$PROJECT.server-0.0.1-alpha/WEB-INF/classes/de/$COMPANY/$PROJECT/server/service/searchengine/ElasticSearch.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;

1)@EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication should be present in the main class
2) Make sure you have the dependency in your pom

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
    or
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  </dependency
```

3)your Elastic class should be annotated with @Component annotated and Injected with @autowired

hope it helps